# Odoo fetch data from webpage

Tags: odoo

Is it possible to fetch data from webpage to Odoo, and how can it be achieved?

For example fetching name, address and country from some webpage to res.partner module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## FROM ODOO

If you speaking about odoo website.

You must create a template view of your website page, a javascript using JSONRPC and odoo (python).

In a first time, you need to create a template view with your button to send data,
the button will calling a javascript method.

Your JS file:

```
odoo.define('your_module.your_website', function (require) {

    "use strict";
    // Odoo class to calling an url with JSONRPC
    var ajax = require('web.ajax');
    $(this).on("click", ".my_button", function () {
        /// Call URL /update_partner with jsonRpc with attribute name, address, country
        ajax.jsonRpc("/update_patner", 'call', {'name': name,'address': address, 'country':'country'})
            .then(function (data) {
                  // Action after update
             });
        }
    }
```

Your python file.

```
from odoo import http

class YourController(http.Controller):
    @http.route(['/update_partner'], type='json', auth="public", methods=['POST'], website=True)
    def update_partner(self, name, address, country, **kw):
       http.request.env['res.partner'].write({'name':name,'address':address, 'country':country})
        return {'result':True'}
```

## FROM OTHER WEBISTE

If you would like updated partner from over website, you can used this documentation of odoo.

https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/api_integration.html

Comment: yep i want to get data from website that are not connected to my odoo server, just some website with info of companys. maybe you can give some simple example how this should be done, because documentations is kinda tricky for me.

Comment: Depends on language you would like used.

Comment: python... i'm a back-end guy and really clueless about front end..  :/

Comment: You can use Flask (http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/). 
With Flask. In the python code. You can use jsonrpclib to get and update data in odoo. 

you can find an example here (python file) https://codeshare.io/2KWKVK and here (html file) https://codeshare.io/5Q83VW

I don't have test the code but it's an example.